# Nativescript: Listview items are reusing when scrolling

Tags: javascript, xml, nativescript

I am trying to add products to Cart by clicking **STORE [`<Label>`].** Then, I am changing label's color for that added list.

After that, I am trying to add more products, by scrolling. Automatically, some other `ListView` list's label color changed.

I know these behaviour will happen in `UITableView` in `iOS`. With the help of `NSDictionary`, I can handle this. [Tableview Reusing in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32351998/uisegment-value-changing-when-tableview-get-scrolled)

I dont know how to handle this in `NativeScript`

**Coding**

**.js**

```
exports.cartColorChange = function(args) {
    var lbl = args.object;
    lbl.color = "rgb(171, 0, 230)";
};
```

**.xml**

```
<ListView col="0" row="2" items="{{ mySecondItems }}" id="myListVw" itemLoading="listViewItemsLoading" itemTap="secondListViewItemTap" class="list-group" separatorColor="transparent">
<ListView.itemTemplate>

<GridLayout class="listGrid" columns="75,*" rows="*" width="100%" height="90" >
  <Label col="0" row="0" class="roundCircle" text="{{ price }}" textWrap="true"  />

  <StackLayout col="1" row="0" orientation="vertical" verticalAlignment="center">
       <Label class="booksubtitle" text="{{ subtitle }}" textWrap="true" id="wow"  />
       <Label class="bookTitle" text="{{ title }}" textWrap="true"  />
       <Label class="addCart" text="&#xf291;" textWrap="true" tap="cartColorChange" />

  </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
</ListView.itemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**.css**

```
Label.addCart{

    text-align: right;
    color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: please add nativescript playground demo.

Comment: I don't know about that.

Comment: play.nativescript.com

Comment: Any help @bhavinjalodara

Comment: please reproduce demo on play.nativescript.com and post the link.

Comment: Is this ok?? https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=9ZZ8OY&v=2

Comment: no it is not okay. search and learn about playground. it is great tool when working with nativescript.

Comment: create NS+JS project in playground reproducing your issue and then post the link.

Comment: I understood Playground. I have tested in my device. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=T6sna8

Comment: icon is not visible in playground demo

Comment: Yes.. but Logic I need.. If u try to scroll means, automatically some other cells's icon color get changed

Comment: icon is not visible in demo. so how can i check color change.

Comment: U just click that icon

Comment: " ? " this icon will come.... click that...

Comment: Any help @bhavinjalodara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are directly changing color of the  rendered object because of which when object is recycled it persist that color.

you can achieve same effect by changing object property when clicked. and based on that property applying styles. like `className="{{isClicked?'clickedCart':'notClickedCart'}}"` or `stle.color="{{isClicked?'red':'blue'}}"`

here is updated playground demo:https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=T6sna8&v=8

**Coding**

**.js**

```
exports.cartColorChange = function(args) {
    var lbl = args.object;
    var item=lbl.bindingContext;
    var index = secondArray.indexOf(item)
    console.log("Clicked item with index " + index);
    item.isClicked = !item.isClicked;
    secondArray.setItem(index,item);
    // lbl.color = "rgb(171, 0, 230)";
};
```

**.xml**

```
<ListView col="0" row="2" items="{{ mySecondItems }}" id="myListVw" itemLoading="listViewItemsLoading" itemTap="secondListViewItemTap" class="list-group" separatorColor="transparent">
<ListView.itemTemplate>

<GridLayout class="listGrid" columns="75,*" rows="*" width="100%" height="90" >
  <Label col="0" row="0" class="roundCircle" text="{{ price }}" textWrap="true"  />

  <StackLayout col="1" row="0" orientation="vertical" verticalAlignment="center">
       <Label class="booksubtitle" text="{{ subtitle }}" textWrap="true" id="wow"  />
       <Label class="bookTitle" text="{{ title }}" textWrap="true"  />
       <Label class="addCart" className="{{isClicked?'clickedCart':'notClickedCart'}}" text="&#xf291;" textWrap="true" tap="cartColorChange" />

  </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
</ListView.itemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**.css**

```
Label.clickedCart{
    color:rgb(171, 0, 230);
}

Label.notClickedCart{
    color:gray;
}
```

Comment: Its working fine. I need, if user want to remove item from cart means, user can CLICK AGAIN to deselect. Then, another thing, 

var lbl = args.object;
var item=lbl.bindingContext
  
 console.log("Row_click_number.   " + item);

Logs
[my iPhone]: "Row_click_number. [object Object]"

Comment: How to I get values of secondArray[0]? If I try to do this means, [object Object] as output showing. But I need, {
    title: "The Programming",
    subtitle: "Programming",
    price: "$15.0"
  }

Comment: Is this possible ? How to do that ?

Comment: i didn't understand what is your question?

Comment: you can do `secondArray.getItem(index)`

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=qwlWK4 , Can u try this for "secondArray.getItem(index)" ? I am getting output as [my iPhone]: "Item Row item with index [object Object]"

Comment: Then how to do DESELECT action in Pink Collar CART ?

Comment: what exactly is your question ? i didn't get it.

Comment: 1. secondArray.getItem(index) , this is not working. 2. From above image [ IN QUESTION], if I click CART icon, it changes to Pink color, then if I tap that again, it should change to Grey Colour . That I need.

Comment: yes. checking. 1. secondArray.getItem(index) , this is not working. This ?

Comment: why you want to do it? you already have object in `item` variable

Comment: I want to print the values in SecondArray. So I am trying to do this, console.log("GetItem  " + secondArray.getItem(index));  I am getting output as, GetItem [object: Object]. But I need, output as, {
    title: "The Programming",
    subtitle: "Programming",
    price: "$15.0"
  }.

Comment: are you a JS noobie also?

Comment: you are printing object as string. it will obviously print [object object] it is basic JS.

Comment: If I want to print values means, what to do ? Any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172892/discussion-between-bhavin-jalodara-and-mcdonal-11).

Comment: My new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262183/assertion-failure-and-nsinternalinconsistencyexception-in-nativescript can u help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes listview items are indeed reused in order to save up memory.

[Here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4469#issuecomment-334079192) you can find the approach used to save your problem which consists in binding the listview item to a certain property in your model.

Comment: My new question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262183/assertion-failure-and-nsinternalinconsistencyexception-in-nativescript can u help me on this?